# In DTW, is the distance the sum of the shortest path's elements or the fathest element?

Tags: dynamic-time-warping

The title says it. In dynamic time warping, I keep hearing that the distance between two distances is the sum of the shortest path's elements. But I also see the distance as the element in the farthest corner? Could somebody please clear this up.

Example:

```
x = [0,1,1,2]
z = [0,2,2]
```

gives this cost matrix:

```
[[ 0. inf inf inf]
 [inf  0.  2.  4.]
 [inf  1.  1.  2.]
 [inf  2.  2.  2.]
 [inf  4.  2.  2.]]
```

meaning that the distance should be 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 5. But every dtw implementation I found returns the distance is 2 (i.e. always returns element in the farthest corner). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a confusion about how the algorithm works.

DTW is inspired by the [Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which is an example of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to calculate the minimum distance efficiently. The main idea is to incrementally calculate the minimum distance between any two subsequences $1..i$ and $1..j$.

So the DTW matrix is not a cost matrix, at least not in the sense of cost between individual positions. any cell in the matrix $m[i,j]$ is the smallest possible distance between the subsequences $1..i$ and $1..j$, so that the last cell $m[m,n]$ *already contains the smallest distance for the full sequences*. In other words there's nothing to sum, actually summing the values doesn't make sense since the larger subsequences include the smaller ones.